# How can I get pdepend to give me accurate results for my extension

Tags: code-analysis, factory

[pdepend](http://pdepend.org/) is a useful tool for doing static analysis on a php codebase, but it doesn't know how to interpret `Mage::(getBlock|getModel|helper|…)` factory methods to their actual classnames. Factories may exist precisely to help relax tight coupling, but for `pdepend` purposes I want it to report on the resolved classnames. For example, if I have

```
$foo = Mage::getModel('eb2caddress/validator')->isValid($address);
```

I would like pdepend to see something like:

```
$v = new EbayEnterprise_Eb2cAddress_Model_Validator();
$foo = $v->isValid($address);
```

I started hacking together a shell script that would automatically do the above conversion, but as I am working on it I'm beginning to realize that I'm going to have a hard time with constructor arguments and singletons. Furthermore, the shell may not be the right approach. Are there any better tools to solve this problem? Even if the end result doesn't use pdepend, any Magento-aware tool (or a tool that can be configured to understand an arbitrary factory) that can tell me various modules' afferent and efferent coupling and relative responsibility as well as a straightforward depgraph would be really helpful.

Is anyone aware of such a tool, or how to get pdepend to understand Magento factories?

Comment: Did you ever try asking them on github? https://github.com/pdepend/pdepend/issues

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support. Contact the developer.

Comment: This question is very relevant in regards to Magento Extension code quality. Unfortunately I don't have an answer, but I don't think it is off topic at all.

Comment: @Vinai I think you can vote to have it reopened.